# What is an algorithm to divide a rectangle into N number of square(ish) cells?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm drawing images on a canvas. I need an algorithm that will help place the images.

I'm trying to keep the aspect ratios of the cells 1:1. This isn't always possible so the idea is that when dividing up a cell if the length is greater than the width then divide the length in half and if the width is greater than the length then divide the cell by its width.

Something like this:
[image]

This would **NOT** be an example of keeping cell aspect ratios 1:1:

[image]

How would I work out the cell sizes and their x and y offset?

```
number of cells = 6
rectangle height = 600
rectangle width = 400

for each cell
  calculate cell height, width, xOffset, yOffset ???
```

Then I can loop through the cells and draw them:

```
for each cell
  draw(xOffset, yOffset, width, height)
```

Comment: Given a 4x6 rectangle divided into 3 cells, [here are three possible solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7f2d.png). Red has perfect squares, but the cells have wildly different areas. Green has cells that are all the same area, but the cells are clearly not square. Blue is the compromise solution: the cell areas are closer than in the red solution, and the cells are more square than in the blue solution.

Comment: The red solution only works in special cases. There isn't always going to be a solution that consists only of perfect squares. I believe that green is always possible, but not necessarily with integer dimensions. As for blue, the problem is that there are two competing objectives: square(ish)ness versus equal areas. So before you can even begin to implement an algorithm to search for blue solutions, you need an objective function that, given a proposed solution, generates a scalar score.

Comment: So my question: which of the three solutions are you looking for?

Comment: @user3386109 I think blue is the best option. Both Squarishness and area would work

Comment: @user3386109 red is also a good option

Comment: Solving the quadratic equation `2W²x² - 2Ax + W² = 0` where `W` is the width of the rectangle, `A` is the area of the rectangle, and `x` is the aspect ratio of the cells gives you the red and green solutions in cases where the red solution exists, and blue solutions otherwise. For example, given a 4x6 rectangle, `W=4`, `A=24` and the solutions are `x=1` (the red solution) or `x=0.5` (the green solution). Given a 4x7 rectangle, `W=4`, `A=28` and the solutions are `x=1.39` (a reddish blue solution) and `x=0.36` (a greenish blue solution). But given a 4x5 rectangle, there are no solutions.

Comment: While the perfect squares of the red solution would only be possible in special cases, you could aim to optimize the aspect ratio. For every rectangle in the arrangement, divide longer edge by shorter edge, then take the maximal value (most non-square ratio) over all the rectangles and minimize that. Perhaps you might need tie breaks later down the line, so instead of just minimizing the maximum, you could sort the values in descending order then minimize them lexicographically, so that you're breaking all ties in favour of local squarishness.

Comment: Note that every example partition shown can be generated by [Mat Timmermann's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72677528/3789665). A single incongruent solution obviously equivalent can be reached for 7&10 cells by placing rows with less cells top & bottom; for 8, 10&11 cells by placing rows with more cells top & bottom.

Comment: (If you don't reward the bounty *now*, half of it will be wasted (if memory serves).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A systematic approach would be to use an integer partition algorithm to generate all possible layouts for a specific N and a goodness function to select the layout with the highest "squarishness."

For example, N=5 has the following 7 possible partitions,

```
5
4 + 1
3 + 2
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

The OP has selected partition 3+2 for the N=5 example layout. For N=10, it is 3+3+2+2 (out of 42). Note that there are two ways to apply a partition to a layout, straight or flipped. N=5 is the only OP example of a flipped layout.

The rectangle has a width of W and a height of H. It holds N rectangular cells, each with a width of w and a height of h. I suggest the following goodness function for the total squarishness,

```
SF = (w1-h1)^2 + ... + (wN-hN)^2.
```

The smaller the SF, the higher the squarishness. When SF is zero, all cells are squares.

Integer partition is a well-studied problem. There are many algorithms in different programming languages on the internet.

---

Here follows an implementation of my proposed solution with two tests related to the OP example. The rectangle is W=4.0 and H=6.0, the same aspect ratio the OP uses.

In the first test, N=5.

```
--- straight ---
5  (45.602)
4 1  (5.7125)
3 2  (3.3125)
3 1 1  (3.44556)
2 2 1  (1.52556)
2 1 1 1  (7.18812)
1 1 1 1 1  (14.45)
```

The integer sequences to the left are the possible partitions of 5. Each sequence represents one possible layout of cells in the rectangle. The number of integers in a partition sequence corresponds to the number of rows. Each integer is the number of cells in a row. The number within parentheses is the SF value for this layout on this rectangle. The lower the SF, the better the squarishness of the layout,

To cover all layout cases, we repeat the above  with the rectangle flipped 90 degrees (by switching W and H),

```
--- flipped ---
5  (14.45)
4 1  (5.7125)
3 2  (0.608333)
3 1 1  (14.9833)
2 2 1  (10.9)
2 1 1 1  (27.875)
1 1 1 1 1  (45.602)
```

The winner is the 3 2 sequence with a flipped layout, as the OP also has it.

In the second test we repeat the above for all N between 1 and 12. But this time, we only keep the winner for each N,

```
--- straight ---
N=1: 1  (1.21)
N=2: 1 1  (0.845)
N=3: 2 1  (1.0275)
N=4: 2 2  (1.21)
N=5: 2 2 1  (1.52556)
N=6: 2 2 2  (0.00666667)
N=7: 3 2 2  (0.407778)
N=8: 3 3 2  (0.808889)
N=9: 3 2 2 2  (0.650625)
N=10: 3 3 2 2  (0.45625)
N=11: 3 3 3 2  (0.261875)
N=12: 3 3 3 3  (0.0675)

--- flipped --
N=1: 1  (1.21)
N=2: 2  (0.845)
N=3: 3  (4.56333)
N=4: 2 2  (1.21)
N=5: 3 2  (0.608333)
N=6: 3 3  (0.00666667)
N=7: 4 3  (0.425833)
N=8: 4 4  (0.845)
N=9: 3 3 3  (1.21)
N=10: 4 3 3  (0.829167)
N=11: 4 4 3  (0.448333)
N=12: 4 4 4  (0.0675)
```

As we can see, the SF goodness function judges the layouts as the OP did in the example, including the flipped N=5.

---

My code is in C++. The integer partition algorithm is from: "Generate all unique partitions of an integer" at geeksforgeeks.org:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

struct Cell {
    double x,y,w,h;
};

using Cells = std::vector<Cell>;

std::string toString(Cell c) { // string representation of Cell
    return "[" + std::to_string(c.x) + "," + std::to_string(c.y) + 
         "," + std::to_string(c.w) + "," + std::to_string(c.h) + "]";
}

double sf(const Cells& cells) { // the squarishness goodness function
    double sf = 0.0;
    for (const Cell& c : cells) sf += (c.w-c.h)*(c.w-c.h);
    return sf;
}

using Partition = std::vector<int>;
using Partitions = std::vector<Partition>;

std::string toString(const Partition& partition) { //  string representation of Partition
    std::string s{};
    for (const int i : partition) s += std::to_string(i) + " ";
    return s;
}

    // modified from: "Generate all unique partitions of an integer" (geeksforgeeks.org).
Partitions allPartitions(const int N) {
    Partitions partitions;
    std::vector<int> p(N);
    int k = 0;

    p[k] = N;
    while (true) {
        partitions.push_back(Partition{});
        std::copy_n(p.begin(), k+1, std::back_inserter(partitions.back()));
        int rem_val = 0;
        while (k >= 0 && p[k] == 1) {
            rem_val += p[k];
            k--;
        }
        if (k < 0) return partitions;
        p[k]--;
        rem_val++;
        while (rem_val > p[k]) {
            p[k+1] = p[k];
            rem_val = rem_val - p[k];
            k++;
        }
        p[k+1] = rem_val;
        k++;
    }
}

     // layout the cubes of a certain partition in a W, H rectangle
Cells fixate_layout(const Partition& p, const double W, const double H) {
    Cells cells;
    const int j_cells = static_cast<int>(p.size());
    const double h = H/j_cells; // height per cell
    for (int j=0; j<j_cells; ++j) { 
        const int i_cells = p[j];
        const double w = W/i_cells; // width per cell
        for (int i=0; i<i_cells; ++i) cells.push_back(Cell(i*w, j*h, w, h));
    }
    return cells;
}

    // find partition with minimal sf of all partitions of N lay ot in a W, H rectangle
std::pair<Partition, double> best_partition(const int N, const double W, const double H) {
    const Partitions partitions = allPartitions(N);
    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    Partition best = {};
    for (const Partition& partition : partitions) {
        const Cells cells = fixate_layout(partition, W, H);
        const double SF = sf(cells);
        if (SF < min) {
            min = SF;
            best = partition;

        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(best, min);
}

    // Prints all partitions of N and the corresponding sf value for an W-H rectangle
void test1(const int N, const double W, const double H) {
    const Partitions partitions = allPartitions(N);
    for (const Partition& partition : partitions) {
        const Cells cells = fixate_layout(partition, W, H);
        const double SF = sf(cells);
        std::cout << toString(partition) << " (" << SF << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
    // Prints the be partition (with the lowest sf value) for all N from 1 up to N
void test2(const int N, const double W, const double H) {
    for (int n=1; n<=N; ++n) {
        const auto& [best, SF] = best_partition(n, W, H);
        std::cout << "N=" << n << ": " << toString(best) << " (" << SF << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

void main_squarish() { // the main function
    const double W = 4, H = 6;
    {
        std::cout << "test 1" << std::endl;
        const int N = 5; // partition N
        std::cout << "--- straight ---" << std::endl;
        test1(N,W,H);
        std::cout << "--- flipped ---" << std::endl;
        test1(N,H,W); // W and H are switched
    }
    {
        std::cout << "test 2" << std::endl;
        const int N = 12; // partitions 1 - 12
        std::cout << "--- straight ---" << std::endl;
        test2(N,W,H);
        std::cout << "--- flipped ---" << std::endl;
        test2(N,H,W); //W and H are switched
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally got round to working on this again and your solution was fantastic. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

This method seems to work out at least as well as all your examples:

1. Consider MxN grids of increasing size until you get to the first one with at least enough cells.  Start with 1x1, and repeatedly add a row or column depending on the resulting aspect ratio.
2. Let D be the difference between the number of cells you have and the number of cells you want.  Reduce the number of cells by 1 in D rows or D columns, distributing the divisions evenly.

If you like, you can then rebalance the row widths or column heights to make sure that all cells have the same aspect ratio.

Here's an implementation in JavaScript.  It will generate a different division every time you run it.

```js
// compute how far an aspect ratio is from square
function aspectError(w,h) {
  return Math.abs(Math.log(w) - Math.log(h));
}

// Calculate a pleasing division between two grids
// returns [average aspect error, division point]
function balance(
  numShort, // number of short rows/cols
  numLong,  // number of long rows/cols
  shortLen, // cells in short ones (long ones are +1)
  T, // transverse dimension
  L // lengthwise dimension
  ){
    // short aspect = div/numshort x L/shortLen
    // long aspect = (T-div)/numLong x L/(shortLen+1)
    // setting equal and solving gives
    // div/(T-div) = (shortLen+1)*numShort/(shortLen*numLong)
    let ratio = (shortLen+1)*numShort / (shortLen * numLong);
    // this point gives both grids the same aspect ratio
    let even =  T * ratio / (ratio+1);
    // Experimentally, this one is more pleaseing
    let div = T*numShort / (numShort + numLong);
    div = (div+even)/2;
    // calculate the average aspect error, plus a penalty for differing area
   
    let err = (
        aspectError(div/numShort,L/shortLen) + 
      aspectError((T-div)/numLong, L/(shortLen+1)) +
      2*aspectError((div/numShort)*(L/shortLen), ((T-div)/numLong)*(L/(shortLen+1)))
      )/2;
    return [err,div];
}

// compute a squarish subdivision
// returns a list of rectangular grids:
// [{x,y,w,h,xdivs,ydivs}]
function squarish(W,H,N)
{
    let xdivs=1
  let ydivs=1
  while(xdivs*ydivs < N) {
    let err1 = aspectError(W/xdivs, H/(ydivs+1));
    let err2 = aspectError(W/(xdivs+1), H/ydivs);
    if (err1 < err2) {
        ydivs+=1;
    } else {
        xdivs+=1;
    }
  }
  // number of rows/cols we have to shorten
  const D = xdivs*ydivs - N;
  if (D<=0) {
    return [{x: 0, y: 0, w: W, h: H, xdivs, ydivs}];
  }
  // decide whether to shorten rows or columns.
  // try both
  let bestCase = null;
  let bestErr = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  if (ydivs == D && xdivs > 1) {
    let err = aspectError(W/(xdivs-1), H/ydivs);
    if (err < bestErr) {
        bestErr = err;
      bestCase = [{x: 0, y: 0, w: W, h: H, xdivs: xdivs-1, ydivs}];
    }
  } else if (ydivs > D && xdivs > 1) {
    // shorten D rows
    // calculate the division point between short and long rows
    // that gives all cells the same aspect
    let [err,div] = balance(D, ydivs-D, xdivs-1, H, W);
    if (err < bestErr) {
        bestErr = err;
      bestCase = [
        {x: 0, y: 0, w: W, h: div, xdivs: xdivs-1, ydivs: D},
        {x: 0, y: div, w: W, h: H-div, xdivs, ydivs: ydivs-D}
      ];
    }
    }
  if (xdivs == D && ydivs > 1) {
    let err = aspectError(W/xdivs, H/(ydivs-1));
    if (err < bestErr) {
        bestErr = err;
      bestCase = [{x: 0, y: 0, w: W, h: H, xdivs, ydivs: ydivs-1}];
    }
  } else if (xdivs > D && ydivs > 1) {
    // shorten D cols
    // calculate the division point between short and long cols
    // that gives all cells the same aspect
    let [err,div] = balance(D, xdivs-D, ydivs-1, W, H);
    if (err < bestErr) {
        bestErr = err;
      bestCase = [
        {x: 0, y: 0, w: div, h: H, xdivs: D, ydivs: ydivs-1},
        {x: div, y: 0, w: W-div, h: H, xdivs: xdivs-D, ydivs}
      ];
    }
    }
  return bestCase;
}


let context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle="#000";

let W=(Math.random()-0.5)*(Math.random()-0.5)*1.9 + 0.5;
let H = 1-W;
{
    let fac = 300/Math.max(W,H);
  W *= fac;
  H *= fac;
}
let N=Math.floor(Math.random()*17+2);
for (const grid of squarish(W,H,N)) {
    for (let y=0; y<grid.ydivs; ++y) {
    for (let x=0; x<grid.xdivs; ++x) {
        let minx = grid.x + grid.w * x/grid.xdivs;
        let maxx = grid.x + grid.w * (x+1)/grid.xdivs;
        let miny = grid.y + grid.h * y/grid.ydivs;
        let maxy = grid.y + grid.h * (y+1)/grid.ydivs;
      context.strokeRect(minx+1, miny+1, maxx-minx, maxy-miny);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="302" height="302">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

Comment: I think dividing it in to columns of cells is possible but not a grid. I think a grid is normally rows and columns. Look at the image above with 5 cells

Comment: Could you add a pseudocode example?

Comment: Sure, I'll put one up today